# Are there scalars $a, b,$ and $c$ such that $A.X = B$ has infinite solutions? And such that the system does not have solutions?

Tags: matrices, algebra-precalculus, determinant, inverse, matrix-equations

$A$ is a $3x3$ matrix. $X$ is the matrix of the unknowns and is $3$ rows by $1$ column. $B$ is the matrix of the solutions and is $3$ rows by a column. And the determinant of $A$ is non-zero ($Det (A) ≠ 0$).

I did the following:

$A.X = B$ Since $Det (A) ≠ 0$, $A$ is reversible. Then, I multiply on both sides of the equality to the left by the inverse of $A$.
We obtain: $A^{-1} .A.X = A^{-1}.B$. Then, $X = A^{-1}$. Now, since the inverse of a matrix is unique then the system has a single solution. Then, there are no scalars $a$, $b$, $c$ such that $A.X = B$ has infinite solutions and neither are such that the system has no solutions.
The scalars are the elements that form the matrix of solutions

Are my demonstration and justification correct?

Comment: Yes, $Ax=b$ has a unique solution when $A$ is invertible (Any 3 tuple $b$ can be uniquely expressed as a linear combination of columns of $A$ ($3$ linearly independent vectors in $R^3$ since determinant in non-zero). This is another way to justify it (existence of $A^{-1}$ if obviously fine too). All this is true assuming that your matrices/vectors are over a field.

Comment: What is $a,b,c$? How do you use these scalars?

Comment: Sorry, the scalars a, b, c  are the elements that form the matrix of the solutions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not explain what these $a,b,c$ really are.
But what you're trying to write is correct, excepting that $X=A^{-1}B$, and not $A^{-1}$.

I'm supposing that you've tried to say that $B=[a\,\,b\,\,c]^{t}$. Even that way the system have one, and only one solution, because you're supposing $det(A)\neq0$. Doesn't matter what B is. Further, you can solve the system $AX=B$ in function of $a,b,c$, and find the solution $S$ for whatever you put into matrix $B$.

Comment: the scalars are the elements that form the matrix of the solutions. I forgot to write it.